# How to call a function everytime my route changes? using useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a chat application and I want to make it like whenever user opens a chat it should show the latest chat.

So to do that I made a function `scrollToBottom()` that scroll to the bottom of the chat after 1 second, but I want to make it run, everytime the route changes. I tried placing `router.query.id` in useEffect dependency but it runs on every second automatically.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      scrollToBottom();
    }, 1000);
 }, [router.query.id]);
```

So basically I want this useEffect to run only when `router.query.id` changes, that is only when the URL changes. How can I do that? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using react-router

Comment: Actually I'm using Next/router. I guess putting `router.query.id` inside useEffect dependency worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next/Router`'s inbuilt events to detect route change.

```
const scroll = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }, 1000);
};

useEffect(() => {
  Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', scroll)

  // Remember to remove event listeners on unmount
  return () => {   
    Router.events.off('routeChangeStart', scroll);
  } 

}, []);
```